# Find character under cursor in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, how can I find the next occurrence of the character under the cursor? I want something like * but for a single character instead of a word.

Example:

```
H|o|w are you?
```

goes to:

```
How are y|o|u?
```

The reason I want it is because there is a strange looking character (one that I don't even know how to type) all over my file and I want to remove them all quickly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following will map `<leader>z` (usually `\z`)

`:nnoremap <leader>z xhp/<C-R>-<CR>`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that works. But it could be shorter if you use yl instead of xhp.

Comment: Instead of `xhp`, `xu` could be used, which would work in the end of lines

Answer (score 94):

Also look at

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (show character under cursor as ascii)

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> (show character under cursor as utf8, including Unicode stuff, hex codes etc)

And most usefully:

<kbd>8</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

```
Find an illegal UTF-8 byte sequence at or after the
        cursor.  This works in two situations:
        1. when 'encoding' is any 8-bit encoding
        2. when 'encoding' is "utf-8" and 'fileencoding' is
           any 8-bit encoding
        Thus it can be used when editing a file that was
        supposed to be UTF-8 but was read as if it is an 8-bit
        encoding because it contains illegal bytes.
        Does not wrap around the end of the file.
        Note that when the cursor is on an illegal byte or the
        cursor is halfway a multi-byte character the command
        won't move the cursor.
```

**Update**

Use **[Tim Pope's `vim-characterize` plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-characterize)** to get full UNICODE names and data:

> In Vim, pressing  `ga`  on a character reveals its representation in
>   decimal, octal, and hex.
>
> Characterize.vim modernizes this with the
>   following additions:
>
> - Unicode character names:  U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SYMBOL
> - Vim digraphs (type after    to insert the character):  Co ,  cO
> - Emoji codes:  :copyright:
> - HTML entities:  ©

Comment: This was pretty useful!

Comment: What is "8 g 8" supposed to do? And where in the Vim help can I find more information about special characters?

Comment: @NielsBom simply `:help g8` in vim

Answer (score 38):

On a single line you can use `fo` and then `;` to go forward (or `,` backward).

On multiple line, you must use `/o` and then `n` to go forward (or `N` backward).

Alternatively, your problem might be solved by using regexp and substitute, ie `:%s/[your odd character]//g`

To manage to copy and paste your "odd character", you should go in visual using <kbd>v</kbd> to select the character, then <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Then type :
`:%s/<CTRL+r>"//g`

`<CTRL+r>"` will copy the content of the copy register in the command line.

Comment: If you can copy the character with `vy`, the third solution should work.

Answer (score 2):

Then simply use a rule to replace them all

```
:%s/search/replacement/
```

This replaces all occurences of `search` with `replacement`.

Comment: But only one per line. You should use the `g` modifier for multiple matches on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

```
:exec '%s/'.getline('.')[col('.')-1].'//g'
```

If it's special character, you'll have to add backslash, but since all special characters are typeable, I suppose it's not.

**Edit:** for it to work with a multi-byte char, replace `getline('.')[col('.')-1]` by `matchstr(getline('.'), '.', col('.')-1)` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23323958/6839774)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one-time quick-hack just use `*`, it will find nothing, but you than press `/`, <up> and edit the pattern. Only works if vim recognizes the character as part of word, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Unforutunately * doesnt take accept my strange character.