# Vim (vimscript) get exact character under the cursor

Tags: vim

I am getting the character under the cursor in vimscript the following way:

```
getline('.')[col('.')-1]
```

It works exactly like it should, however there is something I dislike. consider this `[]` the cursor. When there is a bracket next to the cursor like so:
`}[]` , `][]` , `)[]` or `{[]` the cursor actually returns the bracket. What do I have to set so it will **always** return the character exactly under the cursor or atleast ignore if there is a bracket to it's left?

Note: I suspect that it might have to do with the brackets highlight, though I am not sure.

Note2: for the situation to occur there has to be a matching bracket.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; do you see with with `vim -N -u NONE`? I guess a plugin changes the cursor position.

Comment: I am not using any plugins. I have updated the first post with my vimrc.

Comment: This is wierd. I cleared my vimrc, but they are still highlited. When I run vim with -N -u NONE I don't get this. Does this means that more than one vimrc's are being loaded ?

Comment: Check `:scriptnames` and `:autocmd` for suspicious things.

Comment: In /usr/share/vim/vim74 I have an odd amount of plugins like matchparen (which I think is causing this), spellfire and a bunch of other plugins that shouldn't be there. Are they there by default or have they gotten there in some mysterious way ?

Comment: Turns out I have a bunch of plugins which came preinstalled with vim. I will disable a few and see if I can fix this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Though I cannot reproduce the problem you're describing, there's another problem with your code: Because of the string indexing (and this is one of the uglier sides of Vimscript), it **only works with single-byte characters**, but will fail to capture chars like `Ä` or  (depending on the encoding used). This is a better way of capturing the character under the cursor:

```
:echo matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')
```

---

**Edit:** Since about Vim 7.4.1742, Vim has new `strgetchar()` and `strcharpart()` functions that work with character indexes, not byte addressing. This is helpful in many circumstances, but not here, because you still can only get the byte-index position of the cursor (or the screen column with `virtcol()`, but that's not the same as character index).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will be sure to fix it. +1

Comment: If the above looks like black magic: code just uses cursor's current column-position as an index into a string-representation of the the current line, and echoes whatever character is at that index. The expression yields ```matchstr({currentLineAsStr},"\%{currentColNum}c.")``` where ```\%{number}c``` is an idiom directing the engine to search starting in the {number}th column in the current buffer or in our case just at a certain index in the given string. The ```.``` is the only capturing component of the regex of course just meaning "any single character other than the newline character"

Answer (score 6):

```
nr2char(strgetchar(getline('.')[col('.') - 1:], 0))
```

or

```
strcharpart(getline('.')[col('.') - 1:], 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the character index under cursor that deal with both ASCII and non-ASCII characters is the like the following:

```
function! CharAtIdx(str, idx) abort                                       
  " Get char at idx from str. Note that this is based on character index  
  " instead of the byte index.                                            
  return strcharpart(a:str, a:idx, 1)                                     
endfunction
                                                                          
function! CursorCharIdx() abort                                           
  " A more concise way to get character index under cursor.               
  let cursor_byte_idx = col('.')                                          
  if cursor_byte_idx == 1                        
    return 0                      
  endif                                                                   
                             
  let pre_cursor_text = getline('.')[:col('.')-2]                         
  return strchars(pre_cursor_text)                                        
endfunction
```

Then if you want to get char under cursor, use the following command:

```
let cur_char_idx = CursorCharIdx()
let cur_char = CharAtIdx(getline('.'), cur_char_idx)
```

See also [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28126/15292) on how to get pre-cursor char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works for both ascii and multi-byte characters.

```
echo strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1, 1)
```

**Brief explanation:** with `strpart(s, idx, 1, 1)`
With the last 1, it says, given me 1 character (instead of 1 byte) starting
at byte idx.

This is probably fastest version, no regex, no copy. (Vimscript string is not reference counted, thus slicing will create a copy.)