# vim script exec pastes unformated text

Tags: vim

In all honesty the title is bad. Consider the following 5 lines:

```
function Example()
    let @@ =  "-_-"
    execute  "normal! ]P"
    call cursor(line('.'), col('.')-1) 
endfunction
```

When this function is called, I expect to get `-_-` as output and the cursor should be moved to the left, meaning that it is at the third character, so if I press a key, like I for example I will get `-_i-`

What happens in reality is quite different (and to some degree interesting)
The output the first time this is called is `- _-` and after that it's `_--`

I assume that "cursor" shifts the position of the word under the cursor. 
Basically: Why is it happening? How can I get the desired effect ?

Very important edit:
Apperantly the problem isn't in the plugins. When I go for:

```
call Example()
```

It works flawlessly. Thing is it is supposed to be triggered by a key. I have currently bound it like so:

```
inoremap ' <C-O>: call Example()<CR>
```

So now I am thinking that something in the mapping is broken...

Comment: What do you get when you execute the commands one at a time instead of from `Example()`?  Does it happen on a line where there is no indent, so that `]P` is the same as `P`?

Comment: BTW, you can use `:normal! ]P` instead of `:execute  "normal! ]P"`.

Comment: Yes, I get the same effect even when the commands are executed one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I cannot reproduce your strange behavior. I get `----_-_-_-_-` on repeated invocations, as expected. I again suspect there are plugins at work. Try with `vim -N -u NONE`. As this is a paste, there's little that could influence this function, though. You could try to workaround via `:noautocmd call Example()`, but I'd rather try to find the root cause of this disconcerting strangeness.
- The "-_-" is not a full line, so the `]P` (paste with adapted indent) has no effect here. You could just as well have used `P`.
- To move the cursor one left, rather use `:normal! h`. The subtraction from `col('.')` [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323747/vim-vimscript-get-exact-character-under-the-cursor/23323958#23323958) only works for single-byte ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try to figure out which plugin is causing this. I will keep this open a bit more. And seriously, I appreciate the help, I wouldn't have figured out in a very long amount of time that a plug in might be causing part of the problem.

Comment: Don't you notice any irregularities also during plain editing? With the strange behavior you're describing, it's hard to believe this doesn't affect normal editing (or maybe you don't notice because you're used to it).

Comment: I am probably used to it. I decided to build some small things in vim to better learn it and then I started noticing it. I think that the package I've installed comes with a set of plugins that is causing this (I already found out which plugin was causing the selection problem from the previous question). I will look into it and probably remove the plugins.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? I've never seen such a heavy customization out-of-the-box. I hope you don't use any "distribution" like _spf13_ or _Janus_?! These are known for all the incomprehensive stuff.

Comment: I have updated the first post with new and valuable information. On a side note, I am running ubuntu the package is vim-gnome

Comment: Alright, managed to fix the mapping and everything started working. woohoo